# Variable undefined when it should be visible(defined)

Tags: php, database, variables

I have a bit of a problem when I'm trying to connect to my database in my code, I create a variable which will be used to connect me through functions into my database..

The problem is the functions as I understand don't recognize the variable in the code, and says that it is undefined, I don't understand why it complains when through my logic it shoudn't..

Code:

```
 <?php
class database{
    private $connected = FALSE;
    public function connect(){
        if(!$connected){
            mysql_connect('url', 'user', 'pw');
            @mysql_select_db('db_11765278') or die('Database not found');
            $connected = TRUE;
        }
    }
    public function close(){
        if($connected){
            mysql_close();
            $connected = FALSE;
        }
    }
    public function query($sqlQuery){
        if(!$connected){
            database::connect();
        }
        $result = mysql_query("$sqlQuery");
        if($connected){
            database::close();
        }
        return $result;     
    }
    public function megaQuery($sqlQuery){
        $result = mysql_query("$sqlQuery");
        return $result;
    }
}

?>
```

Regards Alexein!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not referring to the class property with `$this->connected` as you should be doing. `$connect` refers to a local variable, not a property.

Why not [freshen up your knowledge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) a bit?

Comment: u mean I should do that inside the functions?

I'm kinda newbie

Comment: @Alexein, yes inside your functions

Comment: @Alexein: Yes, but only when targeting *properties*. The documentation will explain everything and get you up to speed. I strongly recommend that you read it carefully.

Comment: @Mischa: But when I do it I get this Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in "WHERE_MY_FILE_IS"